# Alt + . (dot) shows &, instead of a previous argument

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, line-editor, zle

I (ab)use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to recover the last argument in a previous command (I'm using **ZSH**): for example,

```
$ convert img.png img.pdf
$ llpp (alt + .) # which produces llpp img.pdf
```

but sometimes I review a pdf with `llpp`

```
$ llpp pdffile.pdf&
```

and then if I try to do something else with `pdffile.pdf` I run into troubles

```
$ llpp (`Alt` + `.`) # produces llpp &
```

So, is there any way to recover `pdffile.pdf` using something similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>?

```
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh
$ echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: What shell are you using? `bash`?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL; echo $TERM;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ESC-.` ([`insert-last-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-insert_002dlast_002dword)) considers any space-separated or space-separable shell token¹ a “word“, including punctuation tokens such as `&`.

You can give it a numeric argument to grab a word other than the last one. Positive arguments count from the right: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is equivalent to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>, **<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>** grabs the previous word, etc. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is the previous word, and negative arguments continue from the left, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is the first argument.

I have [`copy-earlier-word`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-copy_002dearlier_002dword) bound to `ESC-,`. Where repeated invocations of `ESC-.` insert the last word of successive commands going back in the history, repeated invocations of `ESC-,` after `ESC-.` insert the previous word of the same command. So with the following code in your `.zshrc`, you can get the next-to-last word of the previous command with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

```
autoload -U copy-earlier-word
zle -N copy-earlier-word
bindkey '^[,' copy-earlier-word
```

¹  <sub>There are several reasonable definitions of “token” in this context. In this answer I'm going by the definition “something that `insert-last-word` considers to be a separate word”.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In bash, it is possible to prepend a numeric argument to the action.

So, a negative argument of `-1` will address the argument **before**.

You type:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>-<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

Or simply:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>  <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

I don't know how to express that in zsh.

Comment: Zsh has the same feature, but counts in the other direction.